# Why Microsoft Build Tools 2013 not creating v12 folder on test server?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am currently installing Microsoft Build Tools 2013 .
I expect a folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0.

Why it is not getting created or my expectation is wrong?